# Quais algoritmos hash já vem embutidos no PHP?

Tags: php, hash

Recentemente estive procurando algoritmos hash que não fossem os conhecidos `md5`, `sha1` e `sha2`, e que gerassem hashs menores do que os citados.

Foi ai que me peguei pensando, como eu consigo saber quais os algoritmos hash disponíveis para meu uso, no PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O PHP já vem com uma gama de algoritmos hash disponíveis para uso, inclusive ele possui uma função específica para mostrar quais os algoritmos disponíveis, a [`hash_algos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/fa/function.hash-algos.php).

Ao rodar esta função, ela retornará um `array` com todos os métodos disponíveis, exemplo:

```
print_r(hash_algos());
```

O código acima imprimiria o seguinte:

```
Array
(
    [0] => md4
    [1] => md5
    [2] => sha1
    [3] => sha256
    [4] => sha384
    [5] => sha512
    [6] => ripemd128
    [7] => ripemd160
    [8] => whirlpool
    // ...
```

Para utilizar um algoritmo específico você pode usar a função [`hash()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.hash.php), exemplo:

```
echo hash("crc32b", "minha-string");
// imprime: 5373ff38
```